# Objeto de arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, array

Estoy haciendo un sistema de ventas en php y mysql. Las operaciones de base datos las hago con jquery ajax. Guardo cabecera y detalle de la venta por separado, el detalle se va mostrando en una grilla de jqwidgets de la que extraigo su datasource en como un objeto de arrays. Donde cada array del objeto es una columna de la grilla.
Mi duda es como obtener los valores de esos arrays para guardarlos, porque hasta ahora solo me inserta campos null en la bd.
Este es el codigo:

```
 var i = 0;
                 while(dataGrilla[i]){
                     for(var arreglo in dataGrilla) {

                         for(var elemento in dataGrilla[arreglo]){
                             //console.log(elemento);
                             cod_det = dataGrilla['colcodigos'];
                             p_unit = dataGrilla['colprecio'];
                             cantidad = dataGrilla['colcantidad'];
                         }
                         grabaDetServ();
                     }
                     i++;
                 }

function grabaDetServ() {

            var action = 'grabaDet';
            var recargo = 0;
            var folio3 = folio;

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {action: action,cod_sec:cod_sec,cod_det:cod_det,p_unit:p_unit,cantidad:cantidad,folio:folio3},
                    url: '../app/venta.php',
                    success: function () {
                        //toastr.success('Detalle guardado ok');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        toastr.error('Error al guardar detalle');
                    }
                });
            }
```

los datos que quiero saccar de los array son: cod_det,p_unit y cantidad, los demas son fijos.

Comment: Hola @daniel.-, encontraste la respesta? pudiste solucionar el problema?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es DONDE llamar a la funcion `grabaDetServ`, estaba fuera de tu FOR principal, por lo que siempre llegaban como `undefined` los valores ya que en tu codigo tampoco veo que definas las variables. Deberias tener algo asi :

```
var i = 0;
var cod_det = 0;
var p_unit = 0;
var cantidad = 0;
while (dataGrilla[i]) {
    for (var arreglo in dataGrilla) {

        for (var elemento in dataGrilla[arreglo]) {
            //console.log(elemento);
            cod_det = dataGrilla['colcodigos'];
            p_unit = dataGrilla['colprecio'];
            cantidad = dataGrilla['colcantidad'];
            grabaDetServ();
        }

    }
    i++;
}
```

Llamas a la funcionar `grabaDetServ` esos valores no existe, ya que los campos que estas dando valor estan dentro de tu ciclo for interior. Pero llamas a la funcion fuera de ese for.

```
function grabaDetServ() {

    var action = 'grabaDet';
    var recargo = 0;
    var folio3 = folio;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: { action: action, cod_sec: cod_sec, cod_det: cod_det, p_unit: p_unit, cantidad: cantidad, folio: folio3 },
        url: '../app/venta.php',
        success: function() {
            //toastr.success('Detalle guardado ok');
        },
        error: function() {
            toastr.error('Error al guardar detalle');
        }
    });
}
```

O tambien si no quieres declarar las variables con un valor por defecto

```
var i = 0;
while (dataGrilla[i]) {
    for (var arreglo in dataGrilla) {

        for (var elemento in dataGrilla[arreglo]) {
            //console.log(elemento);
            cod_det = dataGrilla['colcodigos'];
            p_unit = dataGrilla['colprecio'];
            cantidad = dataGrilla['colcantidad'];
            grabaDetServ(cod_det, p_unit, cantidad);
        }

    }
    i++;
}
```

Y tu funcion de guardar

```
function grabaDetServ(cod_det, p_unit, cantidad) {
    .....
}
```